# Filter ChartJS using data from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js

I would like to filter my chart by month so I made a `<select>` input above it. The chart is showing properly but when I changed the month options, the data is not updating based on the value selected. Here's what I've done so far:

index.php

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <select class="form-control col-lg-4" name="month">
   <option selected="selected" style="display:none"><?php echo date("F");?></option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
  </select>
</div> 
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'data.php ',
  datatype: 'json',
                
  success: function (result) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    var mychart = new Chart(ctx,
      {
      type: 'bar',
      data: JSON.parse(result),
      options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
        yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
      }
     }
    })
   }
  })};
 </script>
```

data.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","production");

$month = '';

if(isset($_POST["month"]))  
    {  
    $month = $_POST["month"];  
      }  else {  
    $month = date('m');  
    }  

$query = "SELECT finish_date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN customer_type = 'customer_A' THEN order_qty ELSE 0 END) AS custom_A,
        SUM(CASE WHEN customer_type = 'customer_B' THEN order_qty ELSE 0 END) AS custom_B,
        SUM(CASE WHEN customer_type = 'customer_C' THEN order_qty ELSE 0 END) AS custom_C
            FROM production WHERE MONTH(finish_date) = ".$month." GROUP BY finish_date ORDER BY finish_date ASC";

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($date, $custom_A, $custom_B, $custom_C);            

    $labels = array();
    $data_A = array();
    $data_B = array();
    $data_C = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $labels[] = $date;
        $data_A[] = $custom_A;
        $data_B[] = $custom_B;
        $data_C[] = $custom_C;
    }
        $stmt->close();
}

$datasets_A = array('label'=>"A",'data'=> $data_A,'backgroundColor'=>"#D6E9C6");
$datasets_B = array('label'=>"B",'data'=> $data_B,'backgroundColor'=>"#FAEBCC");
$datasets_C = array('label'=>"C",'data'=> $data_C,'backgroundColor'=>"#EBCCD1");

$data = array('labels'=>$labels, 'datasets'=> array($datasets_A,$datasets_B,$datasets_C));

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

How can I make it work? I must have miss something but not sure what it is since I'm not getting any error message.

Comment: I didn't see any code for changing chart value ? or `change` event ?

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: You need to write some code which will take select value and send to your backend page and depending on this return required data and then populate your chart again . Start from writing change event in jquery .

Comment: I put `onchange="update()"` on my select and `function update()` but the chart is not showing. I'm totally ignorant with js and jquery to be honest :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `change` event so that whenever select-box is change the value will be send to your backend and the updated json data will send back as response which you will update in your chart .

***Jquery code*** :

```
window.onload = function() {
  update(); //call your function to update chart
}
//onchange of select
$("select[name=month]").on("change", function() {
  var month = $(this).val() //get value of select
  update(month); //call to update
})

function update(month) {
  var value;
  //if null
  if (month == null) {
    value = "default"; //send some dummy data
  } else {
    value = month; //send actual month
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data.php ',
    data: {
      month: value //send value to backend
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
     //update chart datas
      var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
      var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: JSON.parse(result),
        options: {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: true
            }]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })

}
```

And only change in ***php code*** you need to make is here :

```
if(isset($_POST["month"]) && $_POST["month"] != "default" ){  
    $month = $_POST["month"];  
 }  else {  
    $month = date('m');  
}
```

Comment: it's still not working. I'm totally confused now if it's an issue with my php or jquery code

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console ? Also onload does your chart showing properly using above code

Comment: yes, it is showing correct data on load, I've also tried to run the data.php path on my browser to check if there's any error and everything is okay, data shown is correct and no error messages too.

Comment: Okay can you do `alert(month)` inside change event and see if this gets called ?

Comment: `[object HTMLSelectElement]` this is what the alert says

Comment: I change it to `onchange="update(value)"` and it worked